# Impacts of using Jetty 9.2 with Spark-Java

Tags: maven, jetty-9, spark-java

I want to use Spark-Java 2.0 with Jetty 9.2.  The trick here is that the Maven repository for Spark has dependency on jetty 9.0.  The reason is that we already have working code using 9.2.  When we bind/load the Spark jar at runtime there are class load errors.

The question is what issues may arise for Spark if I do a build to use jetty 9.2?

They other question could be, can I use excludes some how to load Jetty 9.2 over the '*requested*' 9.0 classes?  Is that possible, or will it cause me more bother?

Let me know if you think of other considerations.  Also let me know where to find release notes for Jetty if you can?  I looked for Jetty release notes [here](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/): [Jetty Documentation hub](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/); it is a little disappointing because they simply link to updated manuals.  I look for Release Notes to show me what's different and changed between versions -- A new manual won't help unless I have a way to do '*diff*' on the two manuals.

My thinking is that a jump between 9.0 to 9.2 should be a valid increment.  My thanks in advance for your insights.